# cross-compile qt applications for X11 windowing system

Tags: qt, opengl, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling, x11

I set up a crosscompiler for my raspberry pi 2, to run 
a little GUI project. 
Cross compiling the Qt examples works fine, but when I run 
my own Application, I get a white screen and the following error:

shader compilation failed: 
""

> QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( matrix ): shader program is not linked
>
> QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( opacity ): shader program is not linked
>
> QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( pixelSize ): shader program is not linked

My guess on this is, that the default framebuffer for the cross compiled application ( EGLFS  or LinuxFB according to this [Link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/embedded-linux.html))  doesn't support all features, that are required by the application. So my basic question is:

```
1. How can I cross-compile a qt project, that uses the X11 windowing System?
2  Is there a way to set this in the configure-options of qt?
```

Qt-version: Qt 5.4.1-raspberry

Desktop OS: Ubuntu 14.04

Raspberry Pi OS: raspbian wheezy

Answer (score 0):

I'd first look into why the shader program got not linked in the first place. After shader compilation and linking retrieve the compiler/linker log and print the log messages somewhere. It usually tells you quit exactly, why it doesn't work.